# Youtube Player API android crashes on playback on some devices

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-mediaplayer

This is the stack trace I get from the device (Sony Xperia Miro), when I try to play a video using the Player API.

This is the stack trace for the error. Any assistance is welcome.
The code seems to work fine on some other devices like Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7 etc.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.AdStatsMacros.a(SourceFile:185)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:481)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:467)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:461)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.h(SourceFile:320)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.StatsTracker.g(SourceFile:409)
at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.an.handleMessage(SourceFile:1615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would help if you post the code where you reference the YouTube API that triggers this NullPointerException.

Comment: More data here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604684/youtube-player-for-android-crashes-on-ads-playback

Comment: Yes, this is the exact same issue I am facing, It crashes after the onAdLoaded Callback, So I assume it is something to do with videos with ads pre-rolled in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the native Youtube App. It has been acknowlegded and fixed, in subsequent releases to the Youtube App released by google.

Link here for the same:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431