# YouTube player for android crashes on ads playback

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

We use [Android Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) in out application. Lately I noticed that application crashes every time I try to play a video with enabled ads.

I'm able to reproduce it using their [sample applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications). I've tried SimplePlayerFragment and SimplePlayerView examples. Both crash when I try to cue the http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QudbrUcVPxk video (this is just an example, other videos with ads are failing too).

Here is LogCat output:

> 10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:236)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:555) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:232)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12156) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2565)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2565)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3785) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3758) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3690) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.b(Unknown
>   Source) 10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.h(Unknown Source) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown
>   Source) 10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1111)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1125)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-26 19:10:49.074:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-26 19:10:49.074:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-26 19:10:49.074:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21637): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method) 10-26 19:10:49.074:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.be.a(SourceFile:221) 10-26
>   19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):    at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:233)
>   10-26 19:10:49.074: E/AndroidRuntime(21637):  ... 22 more

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to solve the problem.

UPD:

Thanks to @septagon, found another related LogCat message:

> 10-27 16:58:51.763: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(25196): 
>   apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a:485 Pinging
>   __AWCl-JGAkAHIAQWpAn4krwpwE7A-4AIAqAMBmAQFqgSwAU_QADdeVEnDazwBrSnaYs3R1HBqy45Cu537TEJ3YTBlvSni0sRdoz7KdLcSM8GN-htn40LlHEa78Q0Wc-Hrk04QcefoGDWqXcyn7fC6U9J6CfOz_J6n509CB7hJfQX2xrj2YTLwO2_AeK-bj9k3KWULoKQv_ZBYw5PfzGYPi2xuSOmQuuFoYcr0atVp-oLKiFDMrNiGhAsjaCbg8jlG43cEZZZ-VSGq1f9Oz1b-XQKw4AQBiAXhiftBkgUGCAMQARgBkgUGCAQQBRgKkgUGCAQQARgBkgUGCAYQARgBkgUECAYYA5AGAaAGHNgGAoAHuaXfLA&sigh=PjCzMkHYDKo&cid=5Gi9PCMcr3WKhFJWqILtjrdq&template_id=213">http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/adview?ai=Cr6PgkatsUt7LE8GpmgXc3oHwBbGx9t8DsZHlu3Kx0vmLARABIOP7kwNQ4vr5ivj___AWCl-JGAkAHIAQWpAn4krwpwE7A-4AIAqAMBmAQFqgSwAU_QADdeVEnDazwBrSnaYs3R1HBqy45Cu537TEJ3YTBlvSni0sRdoz7KdLcSM8GN-htn40LlHEa78Q0Wc-Hrk04QcefoGDWqXcyn7fC6U9J6CfOz_J6n509CB7hJfQX2xrj2YTLwO2_AeK-bj9k3KWULoKQv_ZBYw5PfzGYPi2xuSOmQuuFoYcr0atVp-oLKiFDMrNiGhAsjaCbg8jlG43cEZZZ-VSGq1f9Oz1b-XQKw4AQBiAXhiftBkgUGCAMQARgBkgUGCAQQBRgKkgUGCAQQARgBkgUGCAYQARgBkgUECAYYA5AGAaAGHNgGAoAHuaXfLA&sigh=PjCzMkHYDKo&cid=5Gi9PCMcr3WKhFJWqILtjrdq&template_id=213
>   10-27 16:58:51.763: D/AndroidRuntime(25196): Shutting down VM 10-27
>   16:58:51.763: W/dalvikvm(25196): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4158d700) 10-27 16:58:51.773:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-27 16:58:51.773:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25196): java.lang.NullPointerException 10-27
>   16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.AdStatsMacros.a(SourceFile:185)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:481)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:467)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.a(SourceFile:461)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.client.DefaultAdStatsClient.h(SourceFile:320)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.StatsTracker.g(SourceFile:409)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.an.handleMessage(SourceFile:1615)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-27
>   16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-27 16:58:51.773:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 10-27
>   16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-27
>   16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-27 16:58:51.773:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-27 16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-27
>   16:58:51.773: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I've filed an issue on Google's tracker https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431&thanks=5431&ts=1382775701

Comment: What's the Youtube app version on the device?

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya both Nexus 4 and Nexus 10 have 5.2.27 installed.

Comment: We are confirmed that, this will be fixed with YouTube 5.3.

Comment: how can i block the ad on youtube player api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is bug filed in public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431).

[You can track the progress from there](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431).

Bug is also filed internally.

Comment: Great, I filed the bug internally, so you should hear back shortly.

Comment: What's the Youtube app version on the device?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem too using my  Galaxy S4 with the latest version of youtube.
I tried it on my Gnex which does not have the most recent version of youtube and of course everything works fine. seems like the last update made a mess.

Is there any other way to get their attention? is there a way to remove the latest update (just for now, to continue with the development) ?

And for a different topic,  have you tried the getCurrentTimeMillis method more than once a second? do you get different time stamps or just the same when you call it more than once a second (say once every 100ms) ?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Vote for the question to get attention. Yet star the issue I've filed on their tracker https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431&thanks=5431&ts=1382775701

Comment: i uninstalled 5.2.27 and installed 5.1.10 (com.google.youtube-5.1.10.apk) and it works nice.  i found it on http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23134718111255698

Answer (score 0):

Check your unfiltered logcat for a `NullPointerException` coming from `com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.AdStatsMacros`.  If you can find such an error, you're probably having the same problem as I and this question are experiencing.

[Youtube Player API android crashes on playback on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597669/youtube-player-api-android-crashes-on-playback-on-some-devices)

I can confirm that this error has been introduced within the last seventy-two hours and caused a flawlessly-working app to crash whenever an ad tries to play.  The error appears to be coming from deep inside the YouTube Player API jar.  Nothing seems to be confirmed yet, but it looks like YouTube is trying something new on their API back-end and having some troubles.

Comment: Thank you. I've found the LogCat message too. Added the stacktrace to the question and to the issue on Google tracker. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5431